# Cloud ML Engine not working in command line and says it can't find a valid Python Path

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to get prediction from a local model using the gcloud ai-platform command line tool, however I am getting an error "ERROR: (gcloud.ai-platform.local.predict) Something has gone really wrong; we can't find a valid Python executable on your PATH"

The command

`gcloud ai-platform local predict --model-dir={MODEL_PATH} --json-instances={JSON IMAGE} --verbosity debug`

gives the error

```
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.ai-platform.local.predict] with arguments: [--json-instances: "C:\Users\umara\Desktop\DLOCTseg\Normal Image.json", --model-dir: "C:\Users\umara\Desktop\DLOCTseg\export\v1", --verbosity: "debug"]
DEBUG: (gcloud.ai-platform.local.predict) Something has gone really wrong; we can't find a valid Python executable on your PATH.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\umara\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line 985, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "C:\Users\umara\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 795, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "C:\Users\umara\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\surface\ai_platform\local\predict.py", line 79, in Run
    signature_name=args.signature_name)
  File "C:\Users\umara\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\command_lib\ml_engine\local_utils.py", line 86, in RunPredict
    'Something has gone really wrong; we can\'t find a valid Python '
googlecloudsdk.command_lib.ml_engine.local_utils.LocalPredictEnvironmentError: Something has gone really wrong; we can't find a valid Python executable on your PATH.
ERROR: (gcloud.ai-platform.local.predict) Something has gone really wrong; we can't find a valid Python executable on your PATH.
```

However the PATH environment variable contains a valid python. (I have tried two things. Run the command using my systems python version 3.6 or run the command inside an anaconda virtual environment containing python 2.7, and both give the same error)

`echo %PATH%` yields:

`C:\Users\umara\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tf-serving;C:\Users\umara\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tf-serving\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\umara\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tf-serving\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\umara\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tf-serving\Library\bin;C:\Users\umara\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tf-serving\Scripts;C:\Users\umara\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tf-serving\bin;C:\Users\umara\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python36\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\libnvvp;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v714\runtime\win32;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Users\umara\Downloads\ffmpeg-20190114-d52a1be-win64-static\ffmpeg-20190114-d52a1be-win64-static\bin;;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python36\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\libnvvp;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA ;`

and `echo %CLOUDSDK_PYTHON%` yields

`C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe`

I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the cloud sdk but that didn't fix the issue. Could someone please enlighten me as to what the issue could be. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This command[1] requires TensorFlow SDK be installed locally and should use the bundled python installation to run the Cloud SDK.

More info here[2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai-platform/local/predict

[2] https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/getting-started-training-prediction

Comment: Is the Tensorflow SDK different from the Cloud SDK? I have tensorflow gpu installed in my system and the cloud SDK. Do I need to install something else?

Comment: In that case, you'll have to check the PATH. As per checking, Cloud SDK currently doesnt support Python 3 yet[1]. 
You may try pointing CLOUDSDK_PYTHON to Python 2.7.9.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/python/setup#installing_the_cloud_sdk

Comment: I believe Tensorflow for Python 2.7 is not supported on windows as I am unable to install tensorflow. https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?lang=python2